# Method can not be found when using v-on Instance Method

Tags: vue.js

I am using `v-on` in a js template (used later in a component) to fire a click event:

```
v-on='click : favoritesToggle(venue.slug, $event)'
```

however when I clik it I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: scope.favoritesToggle is not a function
```

still the vue object finds it in console:

```
vm.favoritesToggle
> exports.bind(a)
```

I have a few other `v-on` click events on the same page and working well, but they are not inside a js template, could it be something related to not finding the methods because I am triggering on click within a js template?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [docs](http://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices.html#Component_Scope) I understood that methods called within a component should be placed inside that component.

Example:

```
Vue.component('venue-component', {
  template: $('#venue-template').html(),
  methods: {
    favoritesToggle: function (slug, e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      var resource = this.$resource('/api/venues/' + slug + '/favorites_toggle')

      resource.save({
        method: 'like' // unlike
      }, function (data) {})
        .success(function (data, status, request) {
        // handle success
        }).error(function (data, status, request) {
        // handle error
      })
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to post the solution instead of closing the answer immediately, I've been racking my brain on this one. :)